# Why is My Minimax Not Expanding and Making Moves Correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am implementing minimax in Python 2.7.11 in a basic game of Pacman. Pacman is the maximizing agent, and one or more ghosts (depending on the test layout) is/are the minimizing agent(s).

I must implement minimax so that there can be potentially ***more than one*** minimizing agent, and so that it can create a tree of **n plies** (depth). Ply 1, for example, would be each ghost taking a turn minimizing the terminal state utilities of their possible moves, as well as pacman taking his turn maximizing what the ghosts have already minimized. Graphically, ply 1 looks like this:

[image: Ply 1 depth of minimax]

If we had the following arbitrary utilities assigned to the green terminal states (left to right):

`-10, 5, 8, 4, -4, 20, -7, 17`

Pacman should return `-4` and then move in that direction, creating an entirely new minimax tree based on that decision.
First, a list of variables and functions needed for my implementation to make sense:

```
# Stores everything about the current state of the game
gameState

# A globally defined depth that varies depending on the test cases.
#     It could be as little as 1 or arbitrarily large
self.depth

# A locally defined depth that keeps track of how many plies deep I've gone in the tree
self.myDepth

# A function that assigns a numeric value as a utility for the current state
#     How this is calculated is moot
self.evaluationFunction(gameState)

# Returns a list of legal actions for an agent
#     agentIndex = 0 means Pacman, ghosts are >= 1
gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex)

# Returns the successor game state after an agent takes an action
gameState.generateSuccessor(agentIndex, action)

# Returns the total number of agents in the game
gameState.getNumAgents()

# Returns whether or not the game state is a winning (terminal) state
gameState.isWin()

# Returns whether or not the game state is a losing (terminal) state
gameState.isLose()
```

**This is my implementation:**

```
""" 
getAction takes a gameState and returns the optimal move for pacman,
assuming that the ghosts are optimal at minimizing his possibilities
"""
def getAction(self, gameState):
    self.myDepth = 0

    def miniMax(gameState):
        if gameState.isWin() or gameState.isLose() or self.myDepth == self.depth:
            return self.evaluationFunction(gameState)

        numAgents = gameState.getNumAgents()
        for i in range(0, numAgents, 1):
            legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(i)
            successors = [gameState.generateSuccessor(j, legalMoves[j]) for j, move 
                                                           in enumerate(legalMoves)]
            for successor in successors:
                if i == 0:
                    return maxValue(successor, i)
                else:
                    return minValue(successor, i)

    def minValue(gameState, agentIndex):
        minUtility = float('inf')
        legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex)
        succesors = [gameState.generateSuccessor(i, legalMoves[i]) for i, move 
                                                      in enumerate(legalMoves)]
        for successor in successors:
            minUtility = min(minUtility, miniMax(successor))

        return minUtility

    def maxValue(gameState, agentIndex)
        self.myDepth += 1
        maxUtility = float('-inf')
        legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(agentIndex)
        successors = [gameState.generateSuccessor(i, legalMoves[i]) for i, move
                                                       in enumerate(legalMoves)]
        for successor in successors:
            maxUtility = max(maxUtility, miniMax(successor))

        return maxUtility

    return miniMax(gameState)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why my code is doing this? I'm hoping there are a few Minimax/Artificial Intelligence experts out there that can identify my issues.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** by instantiating my `self.myDepth` value as `0` instead of `1`, I have irradicated the exception throwing issue. However, the overall incorrectness of my implementation still remains.

Comment: I don't see the function `getScore()` defined anywhere in your code.  Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: It is within an entirely separate testCases class. I'll add it in, but out of context it may seem a bit bizzare. The more important fact is that this is happening **because** my `self.evaluationFunction(gameState)` is being called before terminal states or maximum depth have been achieved.

Comment: The `if i == 0` line in `miniMax` seems very sketchy to me. That condition is always going to be `True` on the first pass of the outer loop, so the following line will `return` and the other agents will never be considered. Is the indentation in your code correct?

Comment: I made sure my code matched here exactly to what I have, but I see your point. The psuedo code I am working with for `def miniMax(gameState)` says: "1) If state is win/lose/terminal then return utility. 2) If next agent is pacman then return maxValue(gameState). 3) If next agent is ghost then return minValue(gameState)". I saw no other way to keep track of the agents than to use `for i in range(0, numAgents, 1):`

Comment: Well, you can only `return` once per run of the function, so having an unconditional `return` inside a loop makes the later iterations never occur. Perhaps the next agent to act should be part of the `gameState`?

Comment: I changed my instantiation of `self.myDepth` to `0` instead of `1`, which eliminates the exception throwing issue at least.

Comment: `self.myDepth == self.depth` What is going on here?  Is this the max depth check? Where you are incrementing/decrementing self.depth?

Comment: `self.depth` is globally defined, and varies based on the test cases I use to test if my implementation of minimax is generalized enough that it can be passed any amount of agents with any amount of plies. `self.myDepth` is a local variable I instantiate that gets incremented within the `def maxValue(gameAgent, agentIndex, depth)` function, since `maxValue` can only be called once per depth (for Pacman). The line `self.myDepth == self.depth` is checking to see if I have reached the maximum depth defined in my test case.

Comment: 1) What is `self`? `self` is usually what you use for the self reference in class, but it doesn't look like you're doing that here. Is getAction a part of a class? 2) `depth += 1` in the `maxValue` isn't doing anything, you're updating a function parameter and that's not going to be reflected elsewhere

Comment: 1) Again, this is only a fragment of the entire project which consists of over 8000 lines of code. The `self` in `self.depth` and `self.evaluateFunction(gameState)` are part of a class that extends a long hierarchy of agents and objects. They are in the same class as `def getAction(gameState)`, but they **are** correct. The program is written so that my implementation of Minimax is all that matters in my test cases succeeding. 2) You are right, I meant to change that part of the code, as I caught it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out a solution to my issue. The main problem was the fact that I was not referencing the `depth` correctly to keep track of the plies. Instead of incrementing depth within the `maxValue` method, it should instead be passed as a parameter to each function, and only incremented when being passed into `maxValue`. There were several other logical errors such as not correctly referencing `numAgents`, and also the fact that my `miniMax` method was not returning an action. Here is my solution which turned out to work:

```
def getAction(self, gameState):

    self.numAgents = gameState.getNumAgents()
    self.myDepth = 0
    self.action = Direction.STOP # Imported from a class that defines 5 directions

    def miniMax(gameState, index, depth, action):
        maxU = float('-inf')
        legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(index)
        for move in legalMoves:
            tempU = maxU
            successor = gameState.generateSuccessor(index, move)
            maxU = minValue(successor, index + 1, depth)
            if maxU > tempU:
                action = move
        return action

    def maxValue(gameState, index, depth):
        if gameState.isWin() or gameState.isLose() or depth == self.depth:
            return self.evaluationFunction(gameState)

        index %= (self.numAgents - 1)
        maxU = float('-inf')
        legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(index)
        for move in legalMoves:
            successor = gameState.generateSuccessor(index, move)
            maxU = max(maxU, minValue(successor, index + 1, depth)
        return maxU

    def minValue(gameState, index, depth):
        if gameState.isWin() or gameState.isLose() or depth == self.depth:
            return self.evaluationFunction(gameState)

        minU = float('inf')
        legalMoves = gameState.getLegalActions(index)
        if index + 1 == self.numAgents:
            for move in legalMoves:
                successor = gameState.generateSuccessor(index, move)
                # Where depth is increased
                minU = min(minU, maxValue(successor, index, depth + 1)
        else:
            for move in legalMoves:
                successor = gameState.generateSuccessor(index, move)
                minU = min(minU, minValue(successor, index + 1, depth)
        return minU

    return miniMax(gameState, self.index, self.myDepth, self.action)
```

And presto! Our final working multi-agent minimax implementation.